# Matrix rank triangular matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

Does `MatrixRank` check whether a matrix is triangular?
If not, what would be the best way to calculate a matrix rank of a (say upper)triangular matrix in the following practical cases:

1. you have a lot of small matrices,
2. you have a huge dense matrix, and
3. you have a huge sparse matrix?

(Here dense means dense above/below the diagonal)

Comment: Might be of relevant: [Some Notes On Internal Implementation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#30506)

Comment: @bills No, take e.g. { {0,1}, {0,0} }. This one has rank 1 but the diagonal only has 0 elements

Comment: `MatrixRank` utilizes singular value decomposition, and in absence of any more sophisticated methods  (e.g., rank-revealing QR-factorization) in _Mathematica_ I would indeed suggest to use `MatrixRank` or `Length@*SingularValueList`, but only for matrices of size  $m \times n$ where $m$ and $n$ not more than a few thousand.